# Mac OS X - Git repository at user home

Tags: git, macos

I recently wanted to free up some disk space on my mac, and using OmniDiskSweeper, I found that there was a .git folder in /Users/oliverni that took up roughly 25 GB of space.

I was really wondering why this was there, so I used GitHub Desktop to view the repository. Turns out, there was no history, only 77,721 uncommitted changes. I thought this was a little useless, and I wanted to delete it, but I don't know if it's being used by the system or not.

Comment: I don't think system would use a git repository for something, maybe you just inadvertently init you home directory as a git repo sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete it. OS X doesn't even ship with `git` installed by default so rest assured, those are not system files.

*In the future, please direct these types of questions to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) because Stack Overflow is not the correct place to ask. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no system git repository in the OS X home directory. Especially one with a bunch of uncommitted changes. You might have accidentally created it.

The modification date on `~/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample` will give you an idea of when it was made. The modification date on `~/.git/index` will tell you when all those files were added (ie. when it was last used).